# Change order of column display logic in JSP/JSF

Tags: java, jsp, jsf

I have question.

I have a database column as jan, feb,mar till dec and each column will have different values.

I load these values in to Java object as jan, feb, etc. In UI, JSP, I iterate through this list of object and display the columns as jan, feb etc.

But now my requirement is display based on current month.

For example. current month is november, so the columns to be displayed are Nov, Dec,Jan,Feb ... till Oct. So now the order of the column changes based on current month. How do I do these? Any help on the logic would be appreciated?

Regards

Comment: Share your current implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this.

```
<rich:dataTable value="#{aBean.aList}" var="_var">
    <c:forEach var="column" items="#{myBean.columnsList}" >
      <rich:column>
         <f:facet name="header">#{column.headerName}</f:facet>
         Hello!
      </rich:column>
    </c:forEach>
</rich:dataTable>
```

Your bean would be like this.

```
public class MyBean {
  List<String> months = new ArrayList<String>();
  List<Column> columnsList = new ArrayList<Column>();
  String currentMonth = "Apr";

  public MyBean() {//Adding months
    months.add("Jan");
    months.add("Feb");
    months.add("Mar");
    months.add("Apr");
    months.add("May");
  }

  public List<Column> getColumnsList() {//Building columns
    for(int i = months.indexOf(currentMonth); ;) {
      Column c = new Column(months.get(i));
      columnsList.add(c);

      if(i == months.size() - 1) {
        i = 0;
      } else {
        i++;
      }
      if(i == months.indexOf(currentMonth)) {
        break;
      }
    }
    return columnsList;
  }


  public class Column {
    String headerName;
    Column(String headerName) {
      this.headerName = headerName;
    }
    public String getHeaderName() {
      return headerName;
    }
  }
}
```

Change the value of the variable `currentMonth` and check whether it behaves as you expected.
Edit:

---

You have to import the namespace `xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core"`

Comment: I think this looks good. Let me try similar to this and update you. Thanks for the suggestion and help